# How much material would be required to build a giant sun shade to cool down Venus?

Tags: terraforming, planets

One way to terraform Venus would be to create a massive sun shade enveloping the planet. How much actual material would be required for this? And where would you get it from?

Comment: Do you mean a sphere completely surrounding the planet or a disk in between the planet and the sun? (How would you keep either in place?)

Comment: The construction method really rather matters here, but I think that some of the calculations around blocking out the light to Earth may be of use.

Comment: VTC as POB because in the current state answers to this question can vary wildly and still be valid. Previous comments mention nature of the problem.

Comment: Venus is not habitable not only because of the heat, but because of many other things, including the CO2 (which then affects heat). A better way to cool down the planet would be to get rid of the CO2 first.

Comment: You said this is one mentioned way - where was it mentioned? If you provide some context, it might be more clear what kind of shade we're looking it.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding.SE!  We're glad you could join us!  When you have a moment, please [click here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6388/welcome-to-worldbuilding-se?noredirect=1) to learn more about our culture and take our [tour].  SE requires that you provide enough information that a single best answer can be objectively determined, on this site, it means listing criteria explaining how you will judge the answers and details about the question (tech level, application, expected consequence, etc.).  Thanks!

Comment: It wouldn't really sustain on Venus since that planet is full of volcanic activity. Even if you blocked out the sun, you'd have to worry about the heat being trapped inside the planet's atmosphere.

Comment: As a construction idea, would it work to have a ring of material covering the error orbit around the planet, and then have many of those rings in orbits with slightly of slightly different heights? But I guess solar wind will push them into the planet. Maybe have the ring spin a bit faster than orbital speed, so centripetal force countered the solar wind?

Comment: Your question got put `on-hold` this means that you now have the time to add missing details and more precise info as mentioned in the first comments. Once you've edited your question, it will enter the reopen-queue and people with enough rep will check if your question is sufficiently clear, then either vote to reopen it, or provide comment as why they still deem it unfit. This process is an integral part of this site and intended to allow you the time you need to make the question fit, without having people constantly criticizing your question. Looking forqard to the revised version! :d

Answer (score 4):

About 53-ish cubic kilometers of material, assuming that it is only 0.1mm in thickness.

Of course, how you would keep it on station or keep the solar wind from blowing that uber thin 13,000km disk into the planet would be a different problem.

Comment: How many CubeSats worth of sails is that?

Comment: @MichaelKutz Yeah... that looks to be about 7x10^14 cubesats, assuming a 10 square meter Nanosail 7.5 micrometers thick which is a lot less thick than the 100 micrometer I assumed for the sunshade.  [;)

Comment: @IanMoote Don't forget all the micro meteors that will likely turn it into swiss cheese

Comment: Could you make a shade with a smaller radius if you maintained it at a point closer to the sun?

Comment: @tbrookside  I don't believe so.  The Sun is much larger than both the shade and Venus, so the light would skirt around it quite a bit, like the penumbra of an eclipse.  This illustrates it pretty well, from the Wikipedia article about penumbras and antumbras:  https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2e/Diagram_of_umbra%2C_penumbra_%26_antumbra.png

So, if anything, it would have to be larger.  The closer you get to Venus the smaller you can get away with -- roughly 13,000km diameter.

Comment: Looking at the revision history of the question I cannot find any evidence to your claim on top of your answer? Where do you take that info from?

Comment: @dot_Sp0T  My mistake.  You're absolutely correct.  I've removed that note.  Thanks.